# Android Firebase - Reading data from firebase prior to inflating layout

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get a user's profile from a Firebase DB. Then using the user's information I want to set TextViews in my Fragment's layout to reflect the user's individual stats.

The problem is that the rootViw is being returned prior to having recieved the user's profile. And so I get a null object reference error.

My understanding of the fragment's life cycle is that onCreate() is created first and so I tried placing the DB code there but I get the same problem. I then figured that if accessing the DB is slower than my onCreateView() I'll place a Thread.sleep() timer to wait for the DB call to complete and then perform the rest of my code. Which I know is a stupid solution but just wanted to test my theory; that also failed so obviously my understanding is wrong.

Where should I place my DB call so that it completes prior to returning my rootView? Why does placing the DB listener in OnCreate() not work and why does the Thread.sleep() delay not work?

Leaderboard Fragment

```
public class Leaderboard extends Fragment{

    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mUserDatabaseReference;

    private User user;

    private TextView scoreView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_leaderboard, 
                                         container, false);

        scoreView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.leaderboard_score);

        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        final String userUID = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        mUserDatabaseReference = 
                 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

        mUserDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new 
                                                      ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot messageSnap: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        if(messageSnapshot.getKey().equals(userUID)) {
                            user = messageSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        }}}}
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });

        //Causes error because user==null
        scoreView.setText("Score: " + user.getScore());

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Firebase APIs are asynchronous.  You should expect that listeners may be called after *any amount of time*, based on the quality of the hardware and its network connection.  Don't ever use `Thread.sleep()` to try to control the timing of things - that is an anti-pattern.

My suggestion to you is to inflate a "loading" screen in `onCreateView()` to display immediately, so the user doesn't have to look at a blank screen when your fragment starts.  Then, when your listener is called with the data you want to display, add or update other views as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the score after you get the DB result ?

```
mUserDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new 
                                                  ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot messageSnap: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if(messageSnapshot.getKey().equals(userUID)) {
                        user = messageSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    }
                }
                scoreView.setText("Score: " + user.getScore());
                 }}
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
```

Comment: This solution does work but I guess I felt that the listener should be separate from statements that change the view? Maybe my thinking is wrong? Either way thank you!